# Primary decomposition of $(XY,(X-Y)Z)$ in $k[X,Y,Z]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> How to find the primary decomposition of $I=(XY,(X-Y)Z)$ in $R=k[X,Y,Z]$?

It has minimal primes $(x,y),(y,z),(z,x)$. I tried to calculate $J=S^{-1}I\cap R$, where $S=R-(x,y)$, but it seems complicated...

Comment: For such things we have [Macaulay2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=(XY,(X-Y)Z)$. As you observed, $I$ has *three* minimal primes, one of them being $(X,Z)$. We have $I:(X,Z)=(XY,Y^2,(X-Y)Z)$. Using this we get $$I=(XY,Y^2,(X-Y)Z)\cap(X,Z).$$ Set $J=(XY,Y^2,(X-Y)Z)$. Note that $J$ has *two* minimal primes, namely $(Y,Z)$ and $(X,Y)$. We have $J:(Y,Z)=(X-Y,XY,Y^2)=(X-Y,Y^2)$, and therefore $J=(Y,Z)\cap(X-Y,Y^2)$. Finally we have got the primary decomposition, $$I=(Y,Z)\cap(X-Y,Y^2)\cap(X,Z).$$

**Edit.** Let $I$ be an ideal in a noetherian ring $R$ having a unique primary decomposition, $I=Q_1\cap\cdots\cap Q_m$. (This happens, for example, when all the associated primes of $I$ are minimal.) Set $P_i=\sqrt{Q_i}$. Suppose that $(I:P_1)$ has only $m-1$ associated primes. Then $I=P_1\cap (I:P_1)$.

We have $(I:P_1)=(Q_1:P_1)\cap(Q_2:P_2)\cap\cdots\cap(Q_m:P_m)$. Since $P_1\nsubseteq P_i$ for $i\ne 1$ we get $(Q_i:P_1)=Q_i$ for $i\ne 1$. Moreover, if $P_1\neq Q_1$, then $(Q_1:P_1)$ is $P_1$-primary (here I have used that $P_1$ is finitely generated, so some power of $P_1$ is lying in $Q_1$). But we assumed that $(I:P_1)$ has only $m-1$ associated primes, so $P_1=Q_1$. Thus we get $(I:P_1)=Q_2\cap\cdots\cap Q_m$ and hence $I=P_1\cap(I:P_1)$.

Comment: Do you mean $(I\colon (X,Z))=(XY,Y^2,(X-Y)Z)$? How did you calculate it? And how to deduce $I=(I\colon (X,Z))\cap(X,Z)$? Thanks!

Comment: Suppose $I=\cap q_i$ where $\sqrt{q_i}=p_i$, then $I\subseteq(I:p_0)\cap p_0=\cap(q_i:p_0)\cap p_0\subseteq \cap_{p_0-p_j\neq\emptyset}p_j\cap_{p_0\subset p_j}(q_j:p_0)\cap p_0$ How to see the equality $I=(I:p_0)\cap p_0$?

Comment: One more thing: in our case there are no embedded primes, so $p_0\subset p_j$ can't occur. Moreover, $(q_j:p_0)=q_j$ for all $j\ne 0$.

Comment: How to show there are no embedded primes? Sorry I got stuck on this...

Comment: And how to know $(I:(X,Z))$ can be generated by $XY,(X-Y)Z,Y^2$ but no more elements?

Comment: The generators of $I$ form a regular sequence, so $K[X,Y,Z]/I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring. This shows that I has no embedded primes. Btw, I have edited my answer to show that we indeed have $I=(X,Z)\cap(I:(X,Z))$ by using some theoretical arguments. These arguments also apply to $J$, and find $J=(Y,Z)\cap(J:(Y,Z))$.

Comment: Sorry...why can we assume $(I:P_1)$ has $m-1$ associated primes? For example, $(x^2)\cap(x)$ still has $1$ prime ideal and $(x^2:x)\cap(x)=(x)\neq(x^2)$. And a last question is how to see $(I:(X,Z))=(I,Y^2)$ but there's no more generators on the right?

Comment: In the present question $(I:P_1)$ has less associated primes than $I$. (I have written this in italics!) For the last question: clearly $I+(Y^2)\subseteq(I:(X,Z))$. For the other containment take a polynomial $f\in(I:(X,Z))$. Equivalently $Xf\in I$ *and* $Zf\in I$. From $Xf=XYf_1+(X-Y)Zf_2$ we deduce that $X\mid f_2$, so $f_2=Xf_3$. Now we get $f=Yf_1+(X-Y)Zf_3$. From $Zf\in I$ we get $YZf_1\in I$. As before write $YZf_1=XYg_1+(X-Y)Zg_2$ and notice that $Y\mid g_2$. Thus $Zf_1\in(X,(X-Y)Z)=(X,YZ)$. This implies $f_1\in(X,Y)$, so $f\in I+(Y^2)$. (This is what I meant to prove it by calculation)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it helps a lot:)