# How do we find a primary decomposition of an ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Currently I'm reading about primary decomposition of ideals from Atiyah and Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* book. I've read all the theorems related to primary decomposition given in the same book even I don't have any idea of finding a primary decomposition of an ideal. How do we find decomposition of an ideal in general ? For example, here is a problem:

> Let $I=(xy,yz,xw,zw) \subset k[x,y,z,w]$  be an ideal. Find a primary decomposition of $I$.

I'm sorry that I don't have any idea to solve this. Please help!

Comment: Maybe you want to read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/968028/121097) and apply the same strategy to the example you asked for: $I=(xy,x-yz)$.

Comment: @user26857 But thats a bit advanced for me as I don't know anything about regular sequences.Thanks,

Comment: Where I've used regular sequences?

Comment: @user26857  But you have used that decomposition is unique,right?.Is thr any other way to see uniqueness?

Comment: As I said there, this happens when all associated prime ideals are minimal. For instance, in your example I've mentioned above the associated prime ideals are $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ and obviously they are minimal. (If ask this as a separate question I can post an answer, but it would be better if you can figure out by yourself how to find the primary decomposition.)

Comment: @user26857 sorry for replying late.Isn't  because the primary components of any ideal $I$ are uniquely determined by $I$ ?

Comment: Sorry I mean the isolated primary components

Comment: I was saying that because primary components corresponding to minimal prime ideals are uniquely determined by ideal $I$ therefore if all the associated prime ideals are minimal then the decomposition is unique.Right?

Comment: This is right.${}{}$

Comment: @user26857 Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: A primary decomposition of $(xy,x-yz)$ can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385001/what-is-a-primary-decomposition-of-the-ideal-i-langle-xy-x-yz-rangle/385080#385080).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, finding a primary decomposition of an ideal $I$ is a hard problem and is solved by using *Gröbner bases*. That is, there is an algorithm for doing this, but you don't want to do it by hand unless you have lots of time.

For **monomial ideals**, however, the story is different. Here one can often just *see* the decomposition.

Here is a claim: draw a graph with vertices $\{x,y,z,w\}$ and draw an edge between the variables if their product does **not** appear in the ideal. Then the components of this graph correspond to the components of your ideal. In this case we get two components.

-

Here is another way to see this. Think of the variety $V(I) \subset k^4$ defined by your ideal. This consists of all points such that the elements of your ideal evaluates to zero on these. For example, you must have $xy=0$. But then either $x=0$ or $y=0$. In the first case, the ideal reduces to $(yz,zw)$ (suppose $y \neq 0)$, which implies that $z=0$ zero as well. Thus one component of the ideal is $(x,z)$. Similarly, the other component is $(y,w)$.

We conlude that $I= (y,w) \cap (x,z)$.

Comment: Dear Fredrik,Thanks! I can see that $V(I)=V(x,z) \cup V(y,w)$ But how do you get $I$ from this?

Comment: @Learner It is a fact that $I(V(I)) = \sqrt{I}$, so you can recover the ideal from the variety (almost). In this case the ideal is radical, as you we see *a posteriori*, that is, we found a candidate decomposition, which we check is true, and since it is radical, the ideal is radical as well, hence $\sqrt I = I$.

Comment: ,+1 Thanks! But how do we guess In general for example if  $I=(xy,x-yz) \subset k[x,y,z]$ Clearly $V(I)=V(x,y) \cup V(x,z)$ How to proceed further?

Comment: @Learner In that case the ideal isn't radical. What you found implies that $\sqrt I = (x,y) \cap (x,z)$, but $\sqrt I \neq I$. In fact, feeding the ideal to Macaulay2 gives us that $I = (z,x) \cap (yz-x,y^2,xy)$.  (which I'm not sure how to find out by  hand)

Comment: The generator $xy$ is obviously superfluous in the second ideal, so $(xy,x-yz)=(x,z)\cap(y^2,x-yx)$ is a primary decomposition.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Thank you!