# Trying to understand why the associated primes of some ideal are minimal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In a comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/968028/121097) it is mentioned that all the associated primes of $(XY,(X-Y)Z)$ are minimal using some Cohen-Macaulay ring.

> Since I don't know anything about Cohen-Macaulay rings, is there any other way to show that all the associated primes are minimal?

Clearly $V(XY,(X-Y)Z)=V(X,Y) \cup V(X,Z) \cup(Y,Z)$ So we know that the minimal primes are $\{(X,Y),(X,Z),(Y,Z)\}$. But how to show that there is no embedded prime?

**Added:** Is this true that all the embedded primes of $I$ occurs in the decomposition (not the irreducible decomposition, of course, in the irreducible decomposition only minimal primes occurs) of the variety $V(I)$? For example, if $I=(x^2,xy) \subset k[x,y]$ then $V(I)= V(x) \cup V(x,y)$, so here the embedded prime $(x,y)$ also occurs.

Comment: You can alternatively try to show that the ring is reduced, that is, the ideal is radical. But this is not the case for this example.

Comment: @user26857 Is it obvious that $(XY,(X-Y)Z)$ is radical ?

Comment: I said that this is not the case: $(XY,(X-Y)Z)$ is not radical (as shows the primary decomposition I've found in the linked answer).

Comment: @user26857 Sorry..I don't understand your comment.Without primary decomposition how do we check that ring is reduced ? Also if ring is reduced then is there some result about primary decomposition of ideal?

Comment: @Learner By definition, a reduced ring is one which doesn't have non-zero nilpotents, and this is what you can try to show for $R/I$. If the answer is positive, then you can be sure that the ideal $I$ has no embedded prime.

Comment: @user26857 I see..so for example how can we show this  in our particualar example?(without knowing primary decomposition)

Comment: @Learner Please read the above comments.